# Google App Engine 500 internal server error

Tags: cloud, google, google-app-engine, hibernate, springboot

is there any way to solve this probleme but in my local m
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

Answer (score 0):

There is a [thread in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968183/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou/56968373) where this issue is discussed:
To summarise, this is the configuration to implemented that worked.

Set manual configuration for JPA

```
@Bean 
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean(); 

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

JPA by default searches sessionFactory by name 'entityManagerFactory' so change the code to:

```
@Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    return sessionFactory;
}
```